# Eating meat in ראה

Tags: meat, parashat-reeh

I was having a brief flick through the פרשה of ראה and it struck me that there seems to be a very strong theme of eating meat - 3 times a פסוק mentions eating meat to your heart's desire (or similar) but to pour out the blood on the earth.  Then another פסוק mentions the בכור בהמה and then near the end of the פרשה, a final mention of קרבן פסח.  I didn't notice any obvious commentary in the Artscroll Stone Chumash on this, but I haven't looked much further.  Has anyone come across anything interesting on the repetition and why it is mentioned so many times?

Comment: These all seem like reasonable things to mention somewhere. Are you surprised that they are all within a 5 chapter range? I'm not sure what else deserves comment by a commentator.

Comment: Okay, so maybe the last couple of examples aren't so good but it seems very repetitive - 3 times it mentions that you can eat meat but have to pour the blood on to the earth.  Why the repetition?

Comment: @wizzardmr42 Clarifications should be made in the question itself rather than the comments. If you’re changing your question to refer just to the repetition of Kisui HaDam, please [edit] it to say so.

Comment: @DonielF I already did edit the question. I still think the other part is relevant and it isn't just kisui hadam - it also explicitly mentions the permission to eat meat each of the first 3 times

Comment: @wizzardmr42 But you still ask about בכור and פסח

Comment: @DonielF Yes, because I still think that adds to the question